# connection to the server X.X.X.X:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: sockets, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing

im trying to configure a cluster with master and 2 workers on ec2 machines.

I followed the guide on kubernetes and it gave final result of

```
NAME               STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
ip-172-31-13-48    NotReady   control-plane   12m   v1.27.2
ip-172-31-25-211   NotReady   <none>          11m   v1.27.2
ip-172-31-26-181   NotReady   <none>          11m   v1.27.2
```

so it look like it working...
but after few minutes when I run the command `kubectl get nodes` I get:
`The connection to the server 172.31.13.48:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

when Im trying netstat -tlnp to look what going on with 6443 I get this when its not working:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14044/kube-schedule
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6343/kubelet      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43423         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      555/containerd    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      404/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      757/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      757/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      6343/kubelet
```

and this when its working:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name  
tcp        0      0 172.31.13.48:2380       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 172.31.13.48:2379       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43423         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                 
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      -                 
tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Im pretty clueless why 6443 goes on and off

BTW Im a complete beginner in kubernetes, sorry if something not explained well.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: trust you have used 3rd party network plugin kindly refer following link for more details https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/